# How to extract specific text in Google Data Studio?

Tags: regex, case, looker-studio, re2

I've been trying to extract a specific text from a field but it has been impossible so far.

I have a field, `competitors_names`, which contains the name of all the competitors for a specific product (each product is a row).

The problem is that in some cases a competitor has the product published in their web store and in their marketplace store, so it goes like this:

Product x (dimension) --  competitors_names=       Best Buy,Best Buy MKP,Amazon,Ebay

What I'm looking for is to create a dimension that contains all the products where **ONLY** `Best Buy` (not the Market place) is competing.
I've tried with:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(competitors_names, '.(Ebay).') THEN "Ebay"
  ELSE NULL
END
```

But it is including also `Ebay MKP`.

Is there a way to extract **ONLY** `Ebay`? I tried also a filter excluding `Ebay MKP` but it excludes the products where `Ebay` and `Ebay MKP` are competing.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using either **#1** or **#2** below:

### 1) [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724)

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(competitors_names, "^(Ebay)$") THEN "Ebay"
  ELSE NULL
END
```

### 2) [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487)

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(competitors_names, "^(Ebay)$")
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4b305c4d-296c-4753-acb0-2c5970957528) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]